# How can I install ddev/docker on an old, old Mac?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ddev

I am setuping `ddev` over my Mac OS 10.12.6 to access open source project. I am getting below error. I tried to find version which suit to this OS version but no luck. Can anyone help to fix this issue ? I am able to install docker-machine and docker compose.

```
Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> Updated Formulae
Updated 6 formulae.

Warning: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.

==> Installing ddev from drud/ddev
==> Downloading https://github.com/drud/ddev/archive/v1.17.2.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Users/aviboy2006/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/614bf0b8c7b32d6a364c18be4e0b7d95a4466f1e552ebd4a68dc967c9717950e--ddev-1.17.2.tar.gz
==> make VERSION=v1.17.2 COMMIT=v1.17.2
Last 15 lines from /Users/aviboy2006/Library/Logs/Homebrew/ddev/01.make:
COMMIT=v1.17.2

fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
/bin/bash: go: command not found
make: *** No rule to make target `_', needed by `build'.  Stop.

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.12.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Which part of the error message do you have trouble comprehending?

Comment: It was longer so I posted image. Actually installation itself failing to not compatible with os version

Comment: There is a warning and an error message inside your posted image that shows you the problem

Comment: MacOS 10.12.6 is pretty outdated - is there any chance to update your system?

Comment: No that is bigger problem can't upgrade. otherwise I could have opted that option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Homebrew does not support your os version, so you'll need to use the he install_ddev.sh technique. See the script installation technique at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

I imagine you'll also find that docker desktop doesn't support your os version though.

To install via sh script. Can run below script :

`curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/install_ddev.sh && bash install_ddev.sh`

Followup: @aviboy2006 posted a complete tutorial on how to do ddev/docker on an old Mac: https://www.internetkatta.com/installation-of-ddev-docker-and-virtual-box-on-mac-os-10126

Comment: Docker desktop also not supported so install docker machine will this work right ?

Comment: Is there way to replacement of docker desktop ? @rfay

Answer (score 1):

when you get to that stage run

curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drud/ddev/master/scripts/install_ddev.sh && bash install_ddev.sh

checkout the documentation on dudes website[1](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/